# Variable in handler is not passing to template

Tags: go, go-gin

Learning Go and Gin from [here](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/test-driven-development-of-go-web-applications-with-gin). 
So I have a router like this

```
userRoutes.POST("/login", ensureNotLoggedIn(), performLogin)
```

and the handler function is like this

```
func performLogin(c *gin.Context) {
  username := c.PostForm("username")
  password := c.PostForm("password")
  if isUserValid(username, password) {
    token := generateSessionToken()
    c.SetCookie("token", token, 3600, "", "", false, true)
    //is_logged_in is not working in template
    c.Set("is_logged_in", true)
    render(c, gin.H{"title": "Successful Login"}, "login-successful.html")
  } else {
    c.HTML(http.StatusBadRequest, "login.html", gin.H{
        "ErrorTitle":   "Login Failed",
        "ErrorMessage": "Invalid credentials provided",
    })
  }
}
```

and my template is like

```
{{ if .is_logged_in }}
      <li><a href="/article/create">Create Article</a></li>
{{ end }}
{{ if not .is_logged_in }}
    <li><a href="/u/register">Register</a></li>
{{end}}
```

But in the end this variable in template seems not working, only the second section shows, the first link 'Create Article' is always hiding.

**Update**

I changed the handler function to something like this,

```
        render(c, gin.H{"title": "Successful Login", "is_logged_in": c.MustGet("is_logged_in").(bool)}, "login-successful.html")
```

explicitly passing the variable. Now the template element hide and show is correct. So was there anything changed in Golang or Gin to make `.Set()` behaving differently?

Comment: Just for the record, I've just learned that 'this is the way it's supposed to be'. See https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/1512#issuecomment-418021853 — citing @[isgj](https://github.com/isgj) on GitHub, _No, the template can see only what you pass to the `c.HTML(...)`. What you set with `c.Set(...)` can be seen only by the middleware and the handler._

Comment: Also, since this example comes from [this most wonderful tutorial](https://chenyitian.gitbooks.io/gin-tutorials/tdd/11.html) by Chen Yi-Tian, maybe, if someone has a way to contact him, it would be nice if he could update that specific page explaining how variables are passed to templates...

Answer (score 2):

Do you load the template firstly?

```
func main() {
router := gin.Default()
router.LoadHTMLGlob("templates/*")
//router.LoadHTMLFiles("templates/template1.html", "templates/template2.html")
router.GET("/index", func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "index.tmpl", gin.H{
        "title": "Main website",
    })
})
router.Run(":8080")
}
```

templates/index.tmpl

```
<html>
<h1>
    {{ .title }}
</h1>
```